# Creating a list from a from a set of atoms in Prolog

Tags: prolog

Eventually, I will need to create a list of lists in Prolog, but currently, I am having difficulty taking atoms and creating an initial list. I have a cat predicate whose will take in the cat's color and breed.  The name of the cat will represent the name of the list. For example:

fluffy[white, persian]

dante[gray, russian_blue]

I have tried to use the following code to create the first list, but I always get a compilation error:

cat([Color, Breed], Name(Color, Breed), Name).

The error tells me I need a , or a (.

Any thoughts on what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You get a syntax error because the name of a term must be an atom. I.e. in order to avoid the syntax error change `Name(Color, Breed)` e.g. to `'Name'(Color, Breed)`. This probably does not solve the semantic errors in your code though...